# Tomcat 8, Ajax (jQuery), Jersey, REST API não funciona, ativar CORS

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, jersey, cors

Tenho tentado há um tempo configurar o CORS para funcionar com meu Tomcat 8. Mas sempre que tendo submeter a requisição POST, recebo a mensagem de erro:

> "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://rafael.etc' is therefore not allowed access."

`web.xml`:

```xml
 <display-name>apirestex</display-name>
    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>

        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>br.com.resource.api</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>

        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
           <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
           <param-value>/*</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
           <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
           <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Resource:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/usuarios")
public class UsuarioResource {

    @Path("/save")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void save(String conteudo){

        //Usuario usuario  = Usuario.jsonToUser(conteudo);

        System.out.println(conteudo);

        /*return Response.status(200) //200
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia,Authorization")
                .build();*/
    }

}
```

Requisição ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){


    $('#command').on('click', function(){

      var user = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        secondName: $('#secondName').val(),
        sex: $('#sex').val(),
        acessLevel: $('#acessLevel').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        telefone: $('#telefone').val(),
        login: $('#login').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
      }

      $.ajax({

        url:'http://localhost:8282/apirestex/servlet/usuarios/save',
        data:user,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        async:true,
        success: function() { console.log("Success!!!"); },
        error: function() { console.log('Failed!'); },
      });

    });
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

A classe `MyApplication`:

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
  final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

  // register resources and features
  classes.add(UsuarioResource.class);

  return classes;
  }
}
```

No `web.xml`:

```xml
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.resource.api.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

**UPDATE 2**

MyApplication - Adicionei a anotação "@ApplicationPath("/")". E Mudei a MyApplication de package.

```js
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import br.com.resource.api.UsuarioResource;


@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
 @Override
 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
  final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
  
  // register resources and features
  classes.add(UsuarioResource.class);
  
  return classes;
 }
}
```

web.xml

```html
<!-- Register JAX-RS Application, if needed. -->
     <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
         <param-value>br.com.app.api.MyApplication</param-value>
     </init-param>
     
     <!-- Register resources and providers under my.package. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.resource.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

Agora o erro retornado é:

GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [br.com.app.api.MyApplication] in context with path [/apirestex] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at br.com.web.api.OpenCorsFilter.doFilter(OpenCorsFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**SOLVED**

O problema que gerou o erro interno no servidor(500) era que a versão do Jersey (1.9) que eu estava utilizando não era compatível com o JAX-RS 2.0.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs)
 A versão foi alterada.

MyApplication

```js
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import br.com.resource.api.UsuarioResource;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
 @Override
 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
  final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
  
  // register resources and features
  classes.add(UsuarioResource.class);
  
  return classes;
 }
}
```

CORSFilter - Adaptação da classe OpenCorsFilter para funcionar com Jersey 2

```js
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext creq, ContainerResponseContext cres) {

        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authentication, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Codingpedia");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");

    }

}
```

UsuarioResource

```js
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/usuarios")
public class UsuarioResource {

 @Path("/save")
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response save(String conteudo){
  
  System.out.println(conteudo);
  
     return Response.status(200)
             .build();
 }
 
}
```

pom.xml - dependences

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml  - final

```html
   <display-name>apirestex</display-name>
   
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>br.com.app.api.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 
        <!-- Register JAX-RS Application, if needed. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.app.api.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
 
        <!-- Register resources and providers under my.package. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.resource.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
 
        <!-- Register my custom provider (not needed if it's in my.package) AND LoggingFilter. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.web.api.CORSFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>br.com.app.api.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Requisição ajax

```js
$.ajax({

  url:'http://localhost:8282/apirestex/servlet/usuarios/save',
  data: JSON.stringify(user),
  type:'POST',
  crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  async:true,
  success: function() { console.log("Success"); },
  error: function() { console.log();('Failed!'); },
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente acrescentar essa classe no seu projeto:

```java
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*") // Coloque só os padrões que você quer abrir o CORS.
public class OpenCorsFilter implements Filter {

    public OpenCorsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        authorizeCrossDomain((HttpServletResponse) response);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public static void authorizeCrossDomain(HttpServletResponse resp) {
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authentication, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Codingpedia");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
    }
}
```

Supostamente, nada seria necessário de ser acrescentado no `web.xml` porque a anotação `@WebFilter` deveria dar conta disso automaticamente. Mas, se isso não acontecer, adicione isso no `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenCorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.OpenCorsFilter</filter-class> <!-- Use o pacote adequado. -->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenCorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Remova isso do seu `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>

    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
       <param-value>/*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

E remova isso do seu `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Realizei as alterações sugeridas e tive um avanço. Antes minha requisição parava no OPTIONS que é enviado antes do POST, agora ela passa dessa parte. Porém obtenho um 404 como resposta e o System.out.println que coloquei no meu resource não é executado. Até alterei meu resource para que ele envie um _javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(200).build()_ ao invés de void ou String, porém continuei recebendo 404. O que me leva a crer que meu resource de fato não está sendo acessado. Será que algo errado na URI ou no resource?

Comment: @RafaelDias Se você colocou o projeto tendo a raiz em `http://localhost:8282/apirestex`, deveria dar certo. No entanto, a mensagem de erro do CORS fala de uma URL diferente: `http://rafael.etc`

Comment: Boa tarde @Victor Stafusa. 
Desde já agradeço pela ajuda. 
Sim, coloquei na raiz. Sendo "apirestex" o nome do projeto, "servlet" o <servlet-name> configurado no web.xml, "usuarios" o path do recurso, e "save" o nome do método dentro do recurso. 
Acho que pode ter algo relacionado a eu registrar o recurso de alguma forma para ser reconhecido pelo Jersey.

Comment: @RafaelDias Você tem no seu projeto alguma classe que herda de `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`? Além disso, se você tentar abrir no navegador a URL `http://localhost:8282/apirestex` diretamente, o que acontece? Se der um erro 4XX, significa que o servidor está rodando. Se der "Não é possível conectar-se" ou coisa semelhante, então o servidor está rodando no local errado.

Comment: @RafaelDias Após o seu update na pergunta, ainda não funciona?

Comment: EDIT
@VictorSatafusa Mais um avanço. Após mais algumas modificações (farei outro update) agora me retorna um erro 500.

Parece que o problema é que a versão do Jersey (1.9) que estou utlizando não é compativel com o JAX_RS 2.0.
Irei alterar a versão.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs